# unable to start dbconsole service

Tags: oracle, service, oracle11g

My server got rebooted due to unplanned shutdown.After this i am unable to start my dbconsole service.

I also used some techniques like

```
C:\>set ORACLE_HOSTNAME=TEAMCENTER.amwasia.com

C:\>set ORACLE_UNQNAME=PEP

C:\>set ORACLE_SID=PEP

C:\>emctl status dbconsole
```

But i am getting this error only

> Oracle Enterprise Manager 11g Database Control Release 11.2.0.1.0
>   Copyright (c) 1996, 2010 Oracle Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>   https://TEAMCENTER.amwasia.com:1158/em/console/aboutApplication Oracle
>   Enterprise Manager 11g is not running.
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------ Logs are generated in directory
>   C:\APLM\app\infodba\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1/TEAMCENTER.amwasia.com_PEP/sysman/log